# Unknown Provider with AngularJS

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angularjs-scope, angular-services

I would like to create a service and a controller in AngualrJS. The problem is I need to access to $scope in my service.
I think the good solution is to put this service in the controller directly but I have no idea how to do it.
This is my HTML :

```
                <div ng-controller="myController">
                    <input type="text" id="idInput" name="idInput" ng-model="nameModel">
                    <button class="btn btn-default" ng-click="functionWhenClick()">Execute</button>
                </div>
```

This is my controller :

```
var variableModuleName = angular.module("nameModule",[]);
variableModuleName.controller('controllerName',function($rootScope,$scope, CommonService) {
    $scope.nameModel = '';
    $scope.scopeFunctionName = function () {
        CommonService.myFunction($scope.nameModel);
    };
});
```

This is my service :

```
variableModuleName.service('CommonService', ['dataService', function(dataService) {
    this.loadData = function(param) {
        dataService.getCommitData(param).then(function(res) {
            if (res.error) {
                $scope.chartData = res.chartData;
            }
        });
    };

    this.myFunction = function(concatURL){
        this.loadData('URL' + concatURL);
    }
}]);
```

I hope you will can help me.
Thanks.

Comment: the advantage of service is you could share your service object to any controller, as long the service inject into that controller. rather than using $scope.charData, try to define this.charData = '';

Comment: As a sidenode, your code looks a bit messed up, try out John Pappa's styleguide:
https://github.com/johnpapa/angular-styleguide/tree/master/a1

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First of all, You can't/shouldn't use `$scope` in a service. You can't inject `$scope` in the service. You can pass `$scope` as a function's parameter but that's a bad idea. Because, we don't want our service to play with all our `$scope` variables.
Now, to rewrite your service to return `chartData` from an async operation using `dataService` (assuming `dataService.getCommitData(param)` does have a call to server) , you need to handle the promise well.

```
var d3DemoApp = angular.module("D3demoApp",[]);

// service. Assuming dataService exists
d3DemoApp.service('CommonService', ['dataService', function(dataService) {
    this.loadData = function(param) {
        return dataService.getCommitData(param).then(function(res) {
            // Should the if condition be res.error or !res.error
            if (res.error) {
                return res;
            }
        });
    };

    this.myFunction = function(parameterItem){
        return this.loadData('http://localhost:3412/bubble/' + parameterItem);
        console.log("Fonction appellée");
    }
}]);

// controller
d3DemoApp.controller('controllerFilterSearch',function($rootScope,$scope, CommonService) {
    $scope.searchText = '';
    $scope.getSearchText = function () {
        CommonService.myFunction($scope.searchText).then(function(res) {
            $scope.chartData = res.chartData;
        });
    };
});
```

So, in the above code, I am basically returning a promise from `this.loadData` function. When we call `CommonService.myFunction` from controller, we get the response in the `then` resolved callback function and we set the `chartData` from response to `$scope.chartData`.

Comment: Hello, I have the error CommonService is not defined on my controllerBubble : `CommonService.myFunction($scope.searchText);`

Comment: Did you inject `CommonService` in the controller of your application? Also, Check if any typo mistakes exist.

Comment: Yes, did you arrive to make works the Plunker ? You can just put an alert to loadData's body...

Comment: There are many mistakes in your plunker. You didn't even provide the `dataService` service in the plunker. However, I made another plunker using your one. Created a `dataService` service with a `getCommitData` function. Type in the text box and click button and you will get a sample `chartData` object. Please see this [PLUNKER](https://plnkr.co/edit/hYKswsQLFnaiNJ83zyRm?p=preview)

Answer (score 0):

First don't use var `d3DemoApp = angular.module("D3demoApp",[])` through your files.

Use `angular.module("D3demoApp",[])` once to get your module instantiated and then get the reference of the existing one using `angular.module("D3demoApp")`

In your plknr :

1. You forget to include the service file
2. I don't see any definition of the `dataService` which is why you have the `unknown provider dataServiceProvider error`.

Answer (score 0):

There are many ways to do this. My favorite is creating another service which has reference to the scope.

```
d3DemoApp.service('scopeServer', ['dataService', function(dataService) {

     var scope;

     return {
         scope: function(_scope) {
            if (typeof _scope !== 'undefined')
               scope = _scope;

            return scope;
         }
     } 

}]);
```

This service maintains a reference to the scope in a singleton an returns it wherever you call `scopeService.scope();`

You can set the scope in your controller initially.

```
d3DemoApp.controller('controllerFilterSearch',function($rootScope,$scope, scopeServer) {

    scopeServer.scope($scope);

});
```

Answer (score 0):

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

  <head>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="style.css">
    <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.2.15/angular.min.js"></script>
    <script src="controllerInput.js"></script>
    <script src="app.js"></script>
    <script src="serviceInput.js"></script> <!-- Include --> 
  </head>

  <body ng-app="D3demoApp" ng-controller="controllerFilterSearch">
    <input type="text" id="searchTextBox" name="searchTextBox" ng-model="searchText">
    <button class="btn btn-default" ng-click="getSearchText()">Rechercher</button>
  </body>

</html>
```

---

```
var d3DemoApp = angular.module("D3demoApp",[]);
d3DemoApp.controller('controllerFilterSearch',function($rootScope,$scope, CommonService) {
    $scope.searchText = '';
    $scope.getSearchText = function () {
        CommonService.myFunction($scope.searchText);
    };
});
```

Comment: Did you arrive to make works the Plunker ? You can just put an alert to loadData's body...

Answer (score -1):

service

```
d3DemoApp.service('CommonService', ['dataService', function(dataService) {
    this.chartData = '';

    this.loadData = function(param) {
        dataService.getCommitData(param).then(function(res) {
            if (!res.error) {
                this.chartData = res.chartData;
            }

        });
    };

    this.myFunction = function(parameterItem){
        this.loadData('http://localhost:3412/bubble/' + parameterItem);
        console.log("Fonction appellée");
    }
}]);
```

controller

```
var d3DemoApp = angular.module("D3demoApp",[]);
d3DemoApp.controller('controllerFilterSearch',function($rootScope,$scope, CommonService) {
    $scope.searchText = '';
    $scope.getSearchText = function () {
        CommonService.myFunction($scope.searchText);
        $scope.searchText = CommonService.chartData;
    };
});
```